# Move Files in Sequence in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to move folders from 1 to 05 and assigning numbers to them.

Example:

```
test-01 => test-221
test-02 => test-222
test-03 => test-223
test-04 => test-224
test-05 => test-225
```

I've tried this;

```
for num in $(seq -w $2 $3); {
  mv -v "test-$num" "test-$1$num"
}
```

using it like this;

```
./script.sh 2 21 25
```

but I'm getting output;

```
test-21 => test-221
test-22 => test-222
test-23 => test-223
test-24 => test-224
test-25 => test-225
```

which is of course wrong, see example :-)

I've also tried it this way;

```
for a in {1..5}; {
  for b in {21..25}; {
    echo "$a => $b"
  } #b
} #a
```

But I'm getting repeated output like this;

```
1 => 21
1 => 22
1 => 23
1 => 24
1 => 25
2 => 21
2 => 22
2 => 23
2 => 24
2 => 25
3 => 21
3 => 22
3 => 23
3 => 24
3 => 25
4 => 21
4 => 22
4 => 23
4 => 24
4 => 25
5 => 21
5 => 22
5 => 23
5 => 24
5 => 25
```

Comment: In your case, `for i in {1..5}; do mv "test-0$i" "test-22$i"; done` will work. Your question is (very likely) not well posed, as you're asking help on a specific test case, but you're not showing us the big picture and the algorithm you need. Maybe all this is not even very clear in your mind.

Comment: I need it to be called by arguments. Like ./script.sh 1 5 21 25 for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `awk`

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v fa=$1 -v fb=$2 -v ta=$3  'BEGIN {  for(i=fa;i<=fb;i++) printf "test-%02d => test-%02d\n",i,i+ta  }'
```

Test

```
$bash -f main.sh 1 5 220
test-01 => test-221
test-02 => test-222
test-03 => test-223
test-04 => test-224
test-05 => test-225
```

---

Nice looking multi-line code on OP's request

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v fa=$1 -v fb=$2 -v ta=$3  'BEGIN {  
  for(i=fa;i<=fb;i++) 
    printf "test-%02d => test-%02d\n",i,i+ta
}'
```

---

Now actual script for moving files

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -v fa=$1 -v fb=$2 -v ta=$3  'BEGIN {  
  for(i=fa;i<=fb;i++) {
    cmd = sprintf ("mv -v test-%02d test-%02d",i ,i+ta);
    # print cmd;
    system(cmd);
  }
}'
```

Comment: @Tux I believe `awk` can handle maths better way.

Comment: Yeah, I've accepted your answer because it fixes the problem I had with single numbers. So now when I run ./script.sh 01 10 0 it generates; test-01 => test-01 etc... which is very good.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about your example is that its one-liner, could you please add multi-lined commands ? Leave original one too for reference :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Tux We love `awk` one-liners. Updated ans with multiple lines!

Comment: Perfect ^_^ Thank your for your help "jkshah".

Comment: @jkshah: Nice awk one liner +1

Comment: @jkshah, is there a way to define varibles inside sprintf like for example "mv -v $dir/test-%02d $dir/test-%02d" ? Thanks.

Comment: add variable definition with `-v` as done for others. `-v dir=$dir`

Answer (score 1):

```
from_a=1
to_a=5
width_a=2
from_b=220
width_b=3
for a in $(seq $from_a $to_a); do
    printf -v file_a "%0"$width_a"d" "$a"
    printf -v file_b "%0"$width_b"d" $(($a + $from_b))
    echo "test-$file_a => test-$file_b"
done
```

Comment: Yeah this is a mess! no offense.

Comment: Avoid the use of subshell with `printf`, it's ridiculous: `printf -v file_a "%0${width_a}d" "$a"` will work just as well, and will be more efficient.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thank you, I didn't know `printf -v`

Comment: @Tux, mess is writing a nested loop for this.

Comment: @Tux it's not a mess, it's the best solution! It's extendible, parameterisable, and it works properly!

Comment: Yeah well that what I need ;-) But thanks for "arithmetic" idea.

Answer (score 1):

From all the funny discussions we had in the comments (that was a really funny thread), I more or less (probably *less*) understood what you want... or rather, I made my own idea of what I believe you want. Let me rephrase what I understood (and please forgive me if this is not what you exactly requested).

You want a script that will take three non-negative numeric arguments `X`, `Y` and `Z`(with possibly leading `0`'s) with `X<Y` and you want to output `test-M => test-N` where:

- `M` ranges from `X` to `Y`, left-padded with `0`'s so that the number of characters in `M` is the max number of characters in `X` and `Y`
- `N=M+Z`, left-padded with `0`'s so that the number of characters in `N` is the max number of characters of `X`, `Y`, `Z` and `Y+Z`. E.g.,

  ```
  $ ./script 01 04 00220
  test-01 => test-00221
  test-02 => test-00222
  test-03 => test-00223
  test-04 => test-00224

  $ ./script 99 101 0
  test-099 => test-099
  test-100 => test-100
  test-101 => test-101

  $ ./script 99 101 00000
  test-099 => test-00099
  test-100 => test-00100
  test-101 => test-00101

  $ ./script 00 02 99
  test-00 => test-099
  test-01 => test-100
  test-02 => test-101
  ```

Also, you want a bash solution so that you can `mv` the corresponding files without needing to parse the output of another command.

Here we go, and hopefully you'll find some interesting stuff to dig too (remark, the output is of the form `mv -nv xxx yyy` rather than `test-x => test-y`; remove the `echo` when you're happy with this):

```
#!/bin/bash

prepend_source=test-
prepend_target=test-
append_source=
append_target=

shopt -s extglob

die() { printf >&2 "%s\n" "$@"; exit 1; }

is_number() { [[ $1 = +([[:digit:]]) ]]; }

is_in_range() { [[ -z ${1//0/} ]] || [[ ${1/#+(0)} = $((10#$1)) ]]; }

maxlength() {
    local u l=0 retvar=$1
    shift
    for i in "$@"; do
        u=${#i}
        ((u>l)) && ((l=u))
    done
    printf -v "$retvar" "%d" "$l"
}

X=$1
Y=$2
Z=$3

is_number "$X" || die "First argument is not a valid number"
is_number "$Y" || die "Second argument is not a valid number"
is_number "$Z" || die "Third argument is not a valid number"

(( 10#$X <= 10#$Y )) || die "Error: first argument is greater than second"

is_in_range "$X" || die "First argument out of range"
is_in_range "$Y" || die "Second argument out of range"
is_in_range "$Z" || die "Third argument out of range"
(( 10#$Y + 10#$Z >= 0 )) || die "Sum of second and last arguments is out of range"

maxlength "length_s" "$X" "$Y"
maxlength "length_t" "$X" "$Y" "$Z" "$((10#$Y+10#$Z))"

for ((i=10#$X;i<=10#$Y;++i)); do
    printf -v source "%s%.${length_s}d%s" "$prepend_source" "$i" "$append_source"
    printf -v target "%s%.${length_t}d%s" "$prepend_target" "$((10#$Z+$i))" "$append_target"
    # Here we're all done!
    echo mv -nv -- "$source" "$target" || die "Problem in mv" # or another error handle
done
```

I've added the variables `prepend_source`, `append_source`, `prepend_target`, `append_target` at the beginning of the script so that you can replace them easily by what you want. You could add option parsings to be able to set them from the command line (left as an exercise, unless you insist I do it for you).

**Caveat.** The numbers are directly handled by bash, so you must use them from within bash's arithmetic range which is (very likely) on a 64 bits machine: [-9223372036854775808,9223372036854775807]. So there's a lot you can do before reaching that. Now, don't worry, the script will not break if anything goes outside this range because I added explicit checks. If this is truly a limitation, you can always use `bc` or `dc` instead. The `bc` or `dc` implementation is left to the reader as an exercise. By the way, this only works with *non-negative integers*.

---

Is your solution as robust and general as this one?

Comment: appreciate all your efforts. I think sometimes quick and dirty ways are enough to get things done quicker as long as they work for supplied use-case. Isn't it?

Comment: @jkshah true. But quick and dirty ways **are not as much fun**, and are not reusable! moreover, they spread really bad practices over the internet since, e.g., _"ok for this time I'll parse the output of `ls` as `for f in $(ls); do ...; done` because I want to do it quick and dirty, and maybe I'll publish it on the internet because it works"_. Then, someone wanting to learn bash will (oh dear!) read this and use it... until it badly breaks. In fact, I'm really against quick and dirty ways altogether. And the funny thing is that after a while, you do things more robustly in a more natural way!

Comment: Quite true! I hate `ls` in script. +1 for spirit of spreading best script practices! cheers...

Comment: @jkshah And I see a lot of _quick and dirty ways_ that are, in fact, not as quick as more robust methods. It happens! We've seen today a question about putting the directories in an array as `a=( $(ls */) )` (that, we'll all agree is completely broken) whereas the proper `a=( */ )` is quicker and infinitely better.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop. But whichever way you count it, the number you use for one purpose is going to be the wrong number for the other purpose. So you need to use arithmetic to get the right number, e.g.:

```
$(( $num + 220 ))
```

Comment: How can you possibly give an answer without being sure what the OP really wants?

Comment: I am just fixing Tux's immediate problem. That's a valid answer. It's Tux's responsibility to ask the right question.

Comment: Tux's immediate problem is trivially solved by the comment I made to his post.

Comment: Well, I think my solution is better.

Comment: That's your problem then `:D`.

Comment: LOL No fighting please!

Comment: Mind you, your solution is broken when, e.g., `num=08` or more subtle, `num=012` (which might happen, well, we don't know since we don't exactly know what the OP wants). That's because when there's a leading `0`, bash inteprets the number in radix 8. You could fix this as `$((10#$num+220))`, but then you'll have to format this too (again, depending on what the OP wants, we just have no ideas what this guy is trying to achieve).

Comment: Oh my goodness, that's absolutely terrible. Tux: Use a real programming language, then, this is awful.

Comment: LOL Bash is real language ;-)

Comment: Yes, in the sense that it's Turing complete... no, in the sense that you wouldn't implement a payroll system in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have so far;

```
for i in $(seq -w $1 $2); {
  echo "test-$i => test-$((i+$3))"
} #for
```

output I get by running ./script.sh 01 05 220

```
test-01 => test-221
test-02 => test-222
test-03 => test-223
test-04 => test-224
test-05 => test-225
```

so it looks like it matches my example :-)

Comment: Yes, but will fail miserably with `./script.sh 01 08 220`. _Miserably_.

Comment: yeah just noticed that ;-) I get this error > line 6: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08") when I use ./script.sh 01 10 220 is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: There's a way: `$((10#$i+$3))` but this will lead to more subtle bugs depending on how you then need to use this script. Could you please, once for all, show us the big picture, your eventual goal, explained in a generic manner, and not on a test case example???

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all your guys help this is what I have now;

```
for i in $(seq -w $1 $2); {
  echo "test-$i => test-$((10#$i+$3))"
} #for
```

and this is the output I get when I run ./script.sh 01 10 220 for example;

```
test-01 => test-221
test-02 => test-222
test-03 => test-223
test-04 => test-224
test-05 => test-225
test-06 => test-226
test-07 => test-227
test-08 => test-228
test-09 => test-229
test-10 => test-230
```

This was exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks  a lot to "Robin Green" and "gniourf_gniourf".

and now moving of directories work correctly ^_^

```
mv -v "temp/test-$i" "temp/test-$((10#$i+$3))"
```

output of moved directories is;

```
‘temp/test-01’ -> ‘temp/test-221’
‘temp/test-02’ -> ‘temp/test-222’
‘temp/test-03’ -> ‘temp/test-223’
‘temp/test-04’ -> ‘temp/test-224’
‘temp/test-05’ -> ‘temp/test-225’
‘temp/test-06’ -> ‘temp/test-226’
‘temp/test-07’ -> ‘temp/test-227’
‘temp/test-08’ -> ‘temp/test-228’
‘temp/test-09’ -> ‘temp/test-229’
‘temp/test-10’ -> ‘temp/test-230’
```

Problem only occurs when I run; ./script.sh 01 10 0 this is the output I get;

```
test-01 => test-1
test-02 => test-2
test-03 => test-3
test-04 => test-4
test-05 => test-5
test-06 => test-6
test-07 => test-7
test-08 => test-8
test-09 => test-9
test-10 => test-10
```

as you can see no leading zeros =(

Comment: Yeah, but don't try to run it as `./script.sh 01 10 0220` or you'll have surprises!

Comment: Btw, you should have edited your other answer instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Nope the last answer I posted is exactly what I need :-)

Comment: The only problem will this would be when I use single double numbers :-) which then give output without leading zero's

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf appreciate your testing! any counter examples on `awk` solution?

Comment: I don't need leading zero in 3 numbers :-) only in double numbers like 1 to 10 etc...

Comment: @Tux `awk` will handle that problem of leading zero's too. Please check.

Comment: Yeah, just tested that :-)

Comment: @jkshah the `awk` way works, except that you won't get what I expect when running `./script 01 12 0220` (you won't have the leading `0` for the target, but maybe the OP doesn't care about this). The only problem I have with it is that the OP wants to `mv` the files, so he'll have to parse the output of `awk`...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf OP needs only leading zero in case of single digit. and no need to parse output of `awk` for `mv`. awk has `system` function which can handle it with `sprintf`. Check my updated ans.